# How to match parameter names in an expression?

Tags: c#, regex

I have a set of expressions representing some formula with some parameters inside. Like:

```
[parameter1] * [parameter2] * [multiplier]
```

And many others like this.

I want to use a regular expression so that I can get a list of strings (`List<string>`) which will have the following inside:

- `[paramter1]`
- `[paramter2]`
- `[multiplier]`

I am not using regular expressions so often; if you have already used something like this I would appreciate if you can share.

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide some concrete examples. What characters are allowed in parameter1/parameter2/multiplier?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it:

```
\[\w+\]
```

Using .net:

```
string s = "[parameter1] * [parameter2] * [multiplier]";
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(s, @"\[\w+\]");
```

You may want to use a capturing group here: `\[(\w+)\]`, so you have the parameter's name on `Groups[1]`.

Comment: Thanks Kobi! I appreciate all the answers, they were quite useful. But I needed exactly what you have described and for .Net.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what the parameters look like.

The general form for the regular expression will be:

```
\[{something which matches parameter names}\]
```

If the parameter names can only contain letters, digits and underscores, then you will want something like:

```
\[\w+\]
```

This will match parameter names which contain at least one letter, digit or underscore. For example:

```
[parameter]
[parameter1]
[1st_parameter]
[10]
[a]
[_]
```

A more usual limitation is to accept parameter names which contain at least one letter, digit or underscore, but must start with a letter:

```
\[[a-zA-Z]\w*\]
```

Examples include:

```
[parameter]
[parameter1]
[first_parameter]
[a]
```

but it will not match:

```
[1st_parameter]
[10]
[_]
```

However, you might decide that it should match anything between square brackets, and that anything can be a parameter name (maybe you want to validate parameter names at a later stage)

```
\[[^]]+\]
```

will match anything between square brackets so long as it contains at least 1 character.

If you also want to allow empty square brackets (i.e. match `[]`) then you will want:

```
\[[^]]*\]
```

Answer (score 1):

The regex

```
\[[^]]*\]
```

will match anything in square brackets:

```
\[   the opening bracket;
[^]] anything but a closing bracket,
*        repeated zero or more times;
\]   the closing bracket
```

I'm not sure if that's what you asked for, though...

Comment: I suspect the brackets were emphasis and not part of the real string.